# Win 2k12, DirectAccess, EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Background/objective here is to get clients that VPN in to have access to the LAN they are VPN-ing into.  Everything is on EC2.

To get this working, I'm trying to set up direct-access on the Win2k12 box where Remote Access is set-up.  Once of the perquisite checks when you launch the "Enabled Direct Access Wizard" is verifying one of the network adapters is configured to have a static IP address (I do not, nor am I aware of a way to make that a reality on EC2!)  I can choose to suppress that warning and continue...to a point...eventually I am prompted to "Type the public name of IPv4 used by clients..." prompt pictured below.  No value I have tried (host name, fully qualified host name, IP) seems to 
work failing with the below errors

host name : "The public name of IPv4 address is invalid. Modify the settings"

fully qualified host name : "An internal adapter with a valid IP address, IPv6 enabled, DNS settings, and a domain profile cannot be located"

IP: "The public name of IPv4 address is invalid. Modify the settings"

[image]

I'm thinking this could all be due to the failed pre-requisite, though I'm not 100% sure.  Ultimately, I'm beginning to be become unsure if this is possible [by using direct access] or if it is possible to accomplish my goal by using a different approach.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting this up on my 2012 server as well and came across the same error. I had to restart the server after verifying I had a static IP, with it's own IP ad the main DNS and the loopback address as the secondary. This was probably because I said that DNS could only respond on that certain IP.

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment.